# Suggestion template not working in typeahead

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

I am using typeahead to populate search suggestion. I can see the suggestion in console but not able to populate it with html template. Please find my source code below I'm using.

```
     $.typeahead({
            input: '.js-typeahead',
            minLength: 0,
            order: "asc",
            hint: true,
            searchOnFocus: true,
            dynamic: true,
            delay: 500,  
            source: {
                ajax:{
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/my-url/",
                    data: {
                       q1: 'blah',
                       q2: "{{query}}"
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.map(data['data'], function(venue, index) {
                        // console.log(venue["name"])
                            // console.log(venue)
                            return venue;
                        });
                    }
                },

                error: function(err){
                    console.log('ERROR : ', err);
                }
            },
            display: ["name"],
            template: '<div>' +
                        '   <span class="lname">{{name}}</span>' +
                        "</div>",
            debug: true
        });
```

However, It is working fine in console but not able to render it with html.

***Help would be appreciated!***

Comment: which version of typeahead do you use ?

Comment: I am using 3.1.1

Comment: you mean bootstrap isn't it ?

Comment: No it's typeahead version for the same.

Comment: Did u find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You missed an 's' in templates and didn't provide which template. Here's an example where the underlying data is JSON with ID `.id` and text to display `.name`:

```
$('#search').typeahead({
    highlight: true
},
{
    source: bloodhound,
    display: 'name',
    templates: {
        // d looks like { id: 0, name: "Ford", _query: 'fo" }
        // Where id and name are all properties of data objects in the JSON results,
        // and _query is inserted by Typeahead telling you what has been typed so far
        // The code in this method will need to handle highlighting as its own task
        // The outer tag will
        suggestion: d => {
            const s = d.name.replace(d._query, '<strong>$&</strong>');
            return `<div class=simple>${s}</div>`;
        }
    }
});
```